# Ignite AtomicSequence - reset the sequenceName value

Tags: java, ignite

I have a Java app which connects to Ignite as a client with following atomic sequence code

```
@Bean("id")
public IgniteAtomicSequence igniteAtomicSequence(Ignite ignite){
    return ignite.atomicSequence("id", 0, true);
}
```

I started the client with initialValue of 0. Hence sequenceName got created in ignite and I could use api incrementAndGet() to get new value every time.

Now my app is stopped and reconnected as a client and I want to restart with new sequence value of 4000 or any other specific value . But it does not work. I'm still getting value lower than 4000 using api incrementAndGet().

```
@Bean("id")
public IgniteAtomicSequence igniteAtomicSequence(Ignite ignite){
    return ignite.atomicSequence("id", 4000, true);
}
```

Any way to update Ignite Sequence Value without restarting ignite cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You can close current atomic sequence and create a new one.

```
IgniteAtomicSequence id = ignite.atomicSequence("id", 4000, true); 
id.close();
id = ignite.atomicSequence("id", 1, true);
// should be 2
assert id.incrementAndGet() == 2;
```

Reference: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteAtomicSequence.html#close--